# Are there any supported top charts for songs in Esperanto?

Tags: culture, music

Top charts (official or no) with some reputable \ experiensed editors would be of great help to people who are trying to find good music that would also help learning the language and immerse into the culture.

Answer (score 4):

The closest place to documenting popular Esperanto music by sales is [Vinilkosmo](http://www.vinilkosmo.com/). They actually sell downloadable Esperanto music.

Answer (score 4):

There is one on Spotify now! It is based on the number of times each song has been played (which is possible for any user to find out really, just takes some time to check 900 songs).

https://open.spotify.com/user/esperantolisto/playlist/2LZsZqREwg4uX4kG0o18h6

**These are the top 10:**

1. Liza pentras bildojn - Persone
2. Ni chiuj ni - Dolchamar
3. Dankon - Jonny M
4. Televido - La Perdita Generacio
5. La vionolisto - Kaj Tiel Plu
6. Esperanto - Jomo
7. Sub fortepiano en kiev' - La Pedrita Generacio
8. Nun mallumas ekstere - Persone
9. Hieroglifoj - La Porkoj
10. Pli ol nenio - Martin & La Talpoj

Comment: Also check out this list. It contains, if not all, then almost all, Esperanto songs there are to find on Spotify. https://open.spotify.com/user/dotevo/playlist/7LYL5Mcc2oEBphWrKujpq3

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. However, Youtube and Google have their own algorithm for putting the "best" content at the top of the page.
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=esperanto+music

Answer (score 2):

The closest that I know of are the various sites that function as focal points for Esperanto music. *Muzaiko* springs to mind.

http://muzaiko.info/